# Passing each file of a selected Directory

Tags: tcl

Is there any way to pass each and every file (with an extention .tcl) of a selected directory one by one in a particular variable in tcl ?

Comment: What do you mean with 'one by one'? Are you talking about a list or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do what I think you want to do is

```
foreach file [glob -directory $dir *.tcl] {
    # do something with the filename $file
}
```

The `glob` command returns a list of file names that match the pattern in the last argument (in this case `*.tcl`, which means "any name that ends in .tcl"). The `-directory` option specifies which directory to look for files in.

The command will raise an error if there are no files that match the pattern. To avoid this and simply get an empty list, use the option `-nocomplain`.

The `foreach` command takes a variable specification, a list (in this case the list of file names), and a script. The script is evaluated once for every item (or batch of items in some cases) with the variable set to the item.

Documentation:
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[glob](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/glob.htm),
[File name conventions supported by Tcl commands](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/filename.htm)

*Syntax of Tcl string matching:*

- `*` matches a sequence of zero or more characters
- `?` matches a single character
- `[chars]` matches a single character in the set given by *chars* (^ does *not* negate; a range can be given as *a-z*)
- `\x` matches the character *x*, even if that character is special (one of `*?[]\`)